# Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments

Tags: c#, path, environment

When I execute this statement:

```
string folderPath = 
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments);
```

folderPath is set to `C:\ProgramData`.

When I execute this statement in the Immediate Window:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments);
```

`C:\Users\Public\Documents` is displayed (which is what I expected).

Any thoughts on the difference?

UPDATE 7/6/12:

I’m getting different results in different classes in the same exe.

I have one class that lives in a library, and one that’s linked directly into the app.

The library class returns “C:\ProgramData”. 
The linked code returns “C:\Users\Public\Documents”.

Further, the library code returns “C:\ProgramData” for both
“Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments” and
“Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData”.

The linked code returns “C:\Users\Public\Documents” for “Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments” and "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming" for “Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData”.

I’m baffled.

Answer (score 4):

This could happen if your program is 64-bit. Since Visual Studio is 32-bit, when you execute `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments);` in the Immediate Window, it looks up the Windows 32 hive, whereas your program would look up the 64 hive. And it is possible that the CommonDocuments folder has been moved, which would only be registered in the 64 hive.

This is a Windows bug as defined [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/686394/possible-bug-in-environment-getfolderpath-shgetknownfolderpath-with-redirected-public-documents-folder)

**EDIT** Your update says that it is happening in two classes within the same EXE. Since a process can only be 32-bit or 64-bit (not both), this would indicate the above bug does not apply to you (assuming normal comms between the assemblies, not COM with a wrapper for example). Are you able to work it into a suitable test that you can post?

As a quick confirmation, it might also be worthwhile including the following code in each to be doubly sure they are both running in the same process:

```
  Console.WriteLine("{0} Process {1} is {2}bit", GetType().ToString(), System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, IntPtr.Size * 8);
```

Comment: So that's why my files ended up in the wrong place. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 2):

C:\Users\Public\Documents is the right path:

```
Per Machine “Documents”
“Document” type files that users create/open/close/save in the application that are used across users.  These are usually template or public documents.

Example:    MyTemplate.dot
Windows 7:  C:\Users\Public
Vista:  %SystemDrive%\Users\Public
XP: %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Documents
Environment Variable:   Vista/Win7: %PUBLIC%  Note: Does not exist on XP
Known Folder ID:    FOLDERID_PublicDocuments
System.Environment.SpecialFolder:   System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments
CSIDL:  CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS
It’s obvious after looking at all these locations that where you store your files can be challenging if you are targeting multiple OS versions.  The best guidance is to use API’s to find the special folder path.  API’s will return the appropriate location for the target OS.
```

source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions.aspx